# Wordpress: TwentyTen Nav Menu Title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I simply need to remove the HTML title attribute from the link used in the TwentyTen navigation menu.

The theme header file calls this

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

I've tried editing where it builds the links in nav-menu-template.php but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.
Here is a good refrence to implement this.

http://www.tryyourselfs.com/tag/remove-wp_nav_menu-a-title-using-jquery
http://erikshosting.com/tag/wp_nav_menu/
http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/remove-title-attribute-from-wordpress-menu-link/

Comment: Thank Rickys, I went down the jQuery route. The title tag is good for seo, but bad for IE as the cursor looses its hover focus when it rolls over the popup title tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer: [remove title attribute from wordpress menu](http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/remove-title-attribute-from-wordpress-menu-link/comment-page-1/#comment-182942)

Or remove it using jQuery:
in the header.php :

```
$(function() {
    $(“#header a”).removeAttr(“title”);
}
```